# How to SUM Cells with same text on Excel?

Tags: excel

I have something like that on Excel

| row | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Manual | 810 |
| 3 | Manual | 600 |

I want the Cell to check if any G column says Manual, and for every one it does it will then SUM the H column, if it doesn't, it does nothing, the only way I could do it was as bellow:

```
=IF(((G2)="Manual");SUM(H2);"")+IF(((G3)="Manual");SUM(H3);"")
```

If I try something like:

```
=IF((($G$2:$G$3)="Manual");SUM($H$2:$H$3);"")
```

It just give me an error stating an array value could not be found

I have other 99 items and I would like to keep it as clean as possible, can anyone assist?

Comment: `=SUMIFS(H:H,G:G,"Manual")`?

Comment: I have no idea how it was so difficult for me to figure out;
That seems to work, many thanks!

Comment: Use a pivot table.

Answer (score 1):

Below all formula should work for you.

```
=SUMIFS(H:H,G:G,"Manual")
=SUMPRODUCT((H:H)*(G:G="Manual"))
=SUM(FILTER(H:H,G:G="Manual"))
=SUM(IF(G:G="Manual",H:H,0))
```

[image]